# How can I include subfiles in to a subfiles?

Tags: include, subfiles

First of all, I am a newbie here and I have no idea to post a query but I have a problem for which I require your help. I even don't know what should be the title of my problem but what my intuition said, I just titled it above. Apologize if I am wrong. Let me tell you my situation first.

I am writing a problem book in mathematics. The book (say book.tex) is divided in several chapters (say chapter1, chapter2, ..., chapter 7). Each chapter will have three sections: "Notes" followed by "Exercises" and then "Solution" with not less than 100 pages.

I know how to use `\input` or `\include` in a latex document to include multiple files in a single latex document. But while I was doing so, I found that  each chapters are much bigger in amount individually and the latex file itself(for the concerned chapter) is getting bigger. I mean to say that suppose I am writing chapter 1. I found even chapter 1 is getting so bigger that the parts "Notes", "Exercise" and "Solution" are making it too complicated.

So what the alternative I have chosen is that I am writing chapter 1 as another new latex document (say CH1.tex) using `\input` with NotesCH1.tex, ExercisesCH1.tex and SolutionsCH1.tex Once the document for chapter 1 is finished, I will have to copy-paste busyness in the actual chapter1.tex my book.tex file.

Although I am working on this way, but some times its getting too tedious. Because unless the chapters individually are completed, I can't copy them and paste them in the main latex file.

Today I came to know about the package `subfiles`. I have read about it. Tried also and found helpful. It helps to include subfiles in to the main files. So what I did, I created book.tex as master file, under it chapter1.tex as subfile using `\include`. But still my problem is not solved. I found that Notes, Exercise and Solution all must be in the same file chapter1.tex

Can't I do like this: in the chapter1.tex I use `\include` with Notes.tex, Exercise.tex and Solution.tex and run the master file so that every thing will be compiled together?

For the master file Book.tex

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\include{ch1.tex}
\end{document}
```

For chapter 1

```
\documentclass[Book.tex]{subfiles} 
\begin{document}

\include{NotesCh1.tex}
\include{ExerciseCh1.tex}
\include{Solutions.tex}

\end{document}
```

For NotesCh1.tex

```
This is some notes
```

For ExerciseCh1.tex

```
Some exercises
```

For Solutions.tex

```
The solutions
```

I tried as much information about my problem to provide. Please help me. If possible please provide me the latex command or procedures how shall I overcome it. If this has been discussed before, at least provide me that link.

Thanks in advance for your valuable advise

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://goo.gl/Y6FjuF)! You can indent code by 4 spaces, and use backticks to emphasize code inline (``\input``). See [Markdown help](http://tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: @Martin Schroder 
I apologize for my mistake. I forgot to greet all as my mind was very blank during the morning to solve this problem and didn't realize to do it. Thanks for advise sir.

Comment: If you want to adopt the best practice principle, I think you need to put subfiles in a subdirectory and subsubfiles in subsubdirectory, etc. See my answer how I managed a huge project neatly. :-)

Comment: In the main file you write `\include{ch1.tex}` while you claim to use subfiles. You need to write `\subfile{ch1.tex}` to properly use `subfiles` :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think what you want is an easy way to select which part(s) should be compiled in the master file.

---

The following supposes that you have two chapters in the book, and each of them has three sections as you described.

#### STEP 1

This is the master file:

```
% master file: main.tex
\documentclass{book}
\includeonly{chapter1, chapter2}
\begin{document}
\include{chapter1}
\include{chapter2}
\end{document}
```

Chapter 1:

```
% chapter 1, main file
\chapter{This is chapter one}
\input{note1}
\input{exercise1}
\input{solution1}
```

Chapter 2:

```
% chapter 2, main file
\chapter{This is chapter two}
\input{note2}
\input{exercise2}
\input{solution2}
```

In the six subsubfiles, there are some dummy text.

#### STEP 2

Compile the master file, and then, select which chapter you want to compile in `\includeonly{}` (separate eachother by comma).

#### STEP 3

Compile the master file again.

---

You will find that only the chapter(s) you selected was compiled, and the page numbers, chapter and section numbers remains correct.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have a doubt. Sir, I did as you suggested me.    \input has helped me a lot. I did some extra research work and am willing to know this: suppose that in the exercise also I have some three sub exercises. In that case what would you suggest me to do? I extended your idea and find success. Is there any thing would you like to  advise me? Thank you

Comment: @AnjanDebnath, while in standard latex `\include` may not be nested, `\input` may be nested rather deep. How many levels deep generally depends your TeX system, but in mine (TeXLive13 on Windows7) I was able run latex on files that `\input` files thet `\input` files, etc., down to 15th level subfiles. Thus you can easily `\include` chapters that `\input` sections that `\input` exercises that `\input` subexercises, etc.

Comment: @Dan: But how can `\input` knows when it is used in a nested `\input` in a nested directory ?

Comment: @DonutE.Knot: Neither this question nor this answer mentions nested directories, only nesting of `\input` in subfiles. Without additional tools, if subfiles are in subdirectories, one must give `\input` the directory name also (relative to the current directory). Or else the files have unique names and reside in a recursively searchable directory tree in TeX's input path.

Answer (score 7):

Just another approach without loading any package. The feature that I have to emphasize here is that

> `\input` can be nested as long as the files being referenced are all
>   in the same directory. It means that nesting `\input` in nested
>   directory is not possible without additional tricks.

My answer below does the trick so you can have nested `\input`s in nested directories. It is awesome, isn't it? Saving all input files (including sub files) in a single  directory seems to be a bad practice as it makes your life tedious, cumbersome, boring in maintaining them.

### Step 1

Create a package named `mystructuring.sty` as follows.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{mystructuring}[2011/01/12 v0.01 LaTeX package for my own purpose]
%\RequirePackage{needspace}

\newcommand\ContentsPath{Contents/}
\newcommand\ChapterPath{\ContentsPath}
\newcommand\SectionPath{\ChapterPath}
\newcommand\SubSectionPath{\SectionPath}

\@ifclassloaded{book}
{
    \newcommand\IncludeChapter[1]{%
        \renewcommand\ChapterPath{\ContentsPath#1/}%
        \include{\ContentsPath#1}%
    }
    %
    \newcommand\IncludeOnlyChapter[1]{%
        \renewcommand\ChapterPath{\ContentsPath#1/}%
        \includeonly{\ContentsPath#1}%
    }
}{}


\newcommand\InputSection[1]{%
    \renewcommand\SectionPath{\ChapterPath#1/}%
    \input{\ChapterPath#1}%
}


\newcommand\InputSubSection[1]{%
    \renewcommand\SubSectionPath{\SectionPath#1/}%
    \input{\SectionPath#1}%
}


\newcommand\InputSubSubSection[1]{%
    \input{\SubSectionPath#1}%
}

%=====================================================

\@ifclassloaded{book}
{
    \newcommand\Chapter[1]{%
        \chapter{#1}%
        %\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
    }
}{}

\newcommand\Section[1]{%
    %\needspace{3\baselineskip}
    \section{#1}%
    %\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}
}

\newcommand\SubSection[1]{%
    \subsection{#1}%
    %\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#1}
}

\newcommand\SubSubSection[1]{%
    \subsubsection{#1}%
    %\addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{#1}
}

\endinput
% mystructuring.sty
```

### Step 2

Create directory structure for your project as follows.

```
/.../Projects/Project1/Main.tex
...
/.../Projects/Project1/Contents/Chapter1.tex
/.../Projects/Project1/Contents/Chapter1/Section1.tex
/.../Projects/Project1/Contents/Chapter1/Section1/SubSection1.tex
/.../Projects/Project1/Contents/Chapter1/Section1/SubSection2.tex
...
/.../Projects/Project1/Contents/Chapter1/Section2.tex
/.../Projects/Project1/Contents/Chapter1/Section2/SubSection1.tex
/.../Projects/Project1/Contents/Chapter1/Section2/SubSection2.tex
...
/.../Projects/Project1/Contents/Chapter2.tex
/.../Projects/Project1/Contents/Chapter2/Section1.tex
/.../Projects/Project1/Contents/Chapter2/Section1/SubSection1.tex
/.../Projects/Project1/Contents/Chapter2/Section1/SubSection2.tex
...
/.../Projects/Project1/Contents/Chapter2/Section2.tex
/.../Projects/Project1/Contents/Chapter2/Section2/SubSection1.tex
/.../Projects/Project1/Contents/Chapter2/Section2/SubSection2.tex
```

Explanation:

- Each project should be in its own directory.
- In project directory there are a main input file named `Main.tex` and a subdirectory `Contents`. These names should not be changed unless you really want to get dirty by modify the package `mystructuring.sty`.
- There is an input file and a subdirectory for every chapter. For example, `Chapter1` (this name may be changed), its corresponding input file and subdirectory are `Chapter1.tex` and `Chapter1`. Both file name and directory name must be exactly the same but again you may use your own name.
- As the third point said, the rule is also applied to the section.
- In most cases partitioning up to subsections should be more than enough so there is no need to create subsubsection input file. As a result, no subsection subdirectory is needed to create in section directory.

### Step 3

For the sake of simplicity, just download [a dummy project here](http://snk.to/f-chni6mic) and compile with `pdflatex`. No virus attached. The directory and file structure are shown as follows.

[image]

The contents of each input file are given as follows.

- `Main.tex`

  ```
  % Main.tex
  \documentclass{book}
  \usepackage{mystructuring}
  %\IncludeOnlyChapter{Introduction}
  \begin{document}
  \IncludeChapter{Introduction}
  \IncludeChapter{WhatIsTeX}
  \end{document}
  ```
- `Introduction.tex`

  ```
  % Introduction.tex
  \Chapter{Introduction}   

  \InputSection{History}
  \InputSection{CurrentDevelopment}
  ```
- `WhatIsTeX.tex`

  ```
  % WhatIsTeX.tex
  \Chapter{What is \TeX}

  This chapter is intentionally left just for fun!
  ```
- `History.tex`

  ```
  % History.tex
  \Section{History}

  \InputSubSection{BeforeWorldWarTwo}
  \InputSubSection{AfterWorldWarTwo}
  ```
- `CurrentDevelopment.tex`

  ```
  % CurrentDevelopment.tex
  \Section{Current Development}

  \InputSubSection{PSTricks}
  \InputSubSection{TikZ}
  ```
- `BeforeWorldWarTwo.tex`

  ```
  % BeforeWorldWarTwo.tex
  \SubSection{Before World War Two}
  ```
- `AfterWorldWarTwo.tex`

  ```
  % AfterWorldWarTwo.tex
  \SubSection{After World War Two}
  ```
- `PSTricks.tex`

  ```
  % PSTricks.tex
  \SubSection{PSTricks}
  ```
- `TikZ.tex`

  ```
  % TikZ.tex
  \SubSection{TikZ}
  ```

Output to prove that I am not lying now.

[image]

Comment: Its great sir. Thank you so much. I am really grateful to you that you spend your valuable time to figure out my problem. Thank you so much sir.

Comment: This solution does not allow for compiling individual files, does it?