# How to work with command \input{filename.tex}?

Tags: input, folders

I'm writing a book with lots of chapters using a command `\input{filename.tex}` for each chapter in the book `book.tex`. How to make it not to have `book.tex` and all `filename.tex` in the same directory? Is it possible to have directory `book.tex` with subdirectories `filename.tex`?

Comment: `\input{subdirectory/filename}`?

Comment: It might help you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/147503/19356

Answer (score 4):

```
\newcommand\subdir{mysubdir}

...
\input{\subdir/file}
```

Then you have to change only one name if the subdir changes. However, using `\include` instead of `\input` makes more sense if you are using chapters.

Comment: more on when to use `\input` and when to use `\include` can be found [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include).

Comment: I don't know how to do it according to your advice. Let say I have a directory named Work. There is book.tex, file1.tex, file2.tex and file3.tex files in the Work. I would like to have book.tex which will include file1.tex, file2.tex and file3.tex   I put in preambule \newcommand\subdir{book} and then \include{\subdir/file1} \include{\subdir/file2} \include{\subdir/file3} It's not working in this way.

Comment: @Jane -- If all `.tex` files are in the same directory, then you only need to use `\include{file1}`, `\include{file2}` and so on.  Herbert's `\subdir` command suggestion was for a sub-directory under (in this case) the `Work` directory.

Comment: Jon, I don't want to have it like this, because I have so many outputs in one directory and it's so confusing. I want directory Work which will include Book.tex and the Book.tex will include file1.tex, file2.tex and file3.tex, but I cannot find the way how to make it like this.

Comment: @Jane -- Then you need to create sub-directories in the Work directory; e.g., in `Work`, you have the following directories: `chap01`, which includes `ch01.tex`, and `chap02`, which includes `ch02.tex`.  Then `Book.tex` would have `\include{chap01/ch01}` and `\include{chap02/ch02}`.  Obviously under normal circumstances a single command like `\subdir` cannot point to multiple directories....

Comment: Just a suggestion: I've found it much more natural to declare a command along the lines of `\newcommand\includechapter[1]{\input{subdir/#1}}`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a directory struture like the following (where directory `Work` contains the following sub-directories: `Chap01` and `Chap02`, which each have a `.tex` file of their own):

```
Work/
 |-Book.tex 
 |-mystyle.sty
 |-Chap01/
    |-chapter01.tex
 |-Chap02/
    |-chapter02.tex
```

Then the main file would have this basic structure:

```
% Contents of Book.tex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mystyle}
\begin{document}
\include{Chap01/chapter01}% NOTE: these 'sub-files' must not include things like
\include{Chap02/chapter02}%       \usepackage, \begin{document}, or \end{document}
% You could also use \input; for the relative advantages, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246/8528
% \input{Chap01/chapter01}
% \input{Chap02/chapter02}
\end{document}
```

And the included files would look something like this:

```
% Contents of chapter01.tex
\chapter{The First Chapter}
This is the first chapter.
```

Comment: There's no need to use `\include`; also `\input` will accept a subdirectory prefix.

Comment: @egreg -- Yes indeed (will edit).  For chapters, I recommend `\include` mainly because of the possibility to use `\includeonly`.

Comment: Well, it seems very complicated for me. I tried to do it like this but it writes mystyle.sty is not defined.

Comment: @Jane -- Just omit that line: `\usepackage{mystyle}` was invented simply to point out that you would load "personal" packages normally in comparison with `.tex` files located in sub-directories.

Comment: It works now fine.Thans a lot.I am just wondering if it could be proved.I'm using some pictures in almost each chapter.I thought it would be enough just keep the pictures in each chapter directory together with chapter.tex, but I was supposed to put all pictures in work directory together with book.tex. So I still have with book. tex lots of pictures there.

Comment: @Jane -- I'm sorry but that is not clear: what do you mean by 'supposed'?  According to whom?  You can (1) keep all your pictures in the main 'Work' directory; (2) put all pictures in a separate directory (called, e.g., 'graphics'); or (3) put pictures corresponding to each chapter in the appropriate chapter directory.  Note that `graphicx.sty` has a useful command called `\graphicspath` -- please refer to the documentation for use with different operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

You need a folder Work/Book with the chapter .tex files in there in order for this to work.

Alternatively, you can give a path for each `\include`, relative to the path of yout main .tex file, directly in the curly braces so you don't need the `\subdir` definition. Just remember to use / instead of \ to concatenate folders in the path.